# Laravel 4 eloquent relationsips

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationships

I have three models: 
Category, Company and Product.

Category
 id, name
Company
 id, category_id, name
Product
 id, company_id, name

I want to get all products with company and category of this company.
So, for ex.:
*Guitar from RainSong which belongs to Music Category*

How I should setup models to do that?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Code::with('company', 'company.category')->get();

Answer (score -1):

Use where() instead of with(). with() method is used for [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

Suggest you read through [Laravel Eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) first.

```
Product::select('product.*')
        ->join('company','company.company_id','=','product.company_id')
        ->join('category','category.category_id','=','company.category_id')
        ->where('category.category_id','=', $input)
```

Comment: Doesn't actually address the problem. with() is exactly what they were after to pull in the information.